# Approximate unitary equivalence (relative to the compacts)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

There is a quotation below:

Definition 1.7.2. Two maps $\pi: A\rightarrow B(H)$ and $\sigma: A\rightarrow B(K)$ are called **approximately unitarily equivalent** if there is a sequence of unitary operators $U_{n}: H \rightarrow K$ such that 
$$||\sigma(a)-U_{n}\pi(a)U_{n}^{*}||\rightarrow 0$$

for all $a\in A$. If it also happens that $\sigma(a)-U_{n}\pi(a)U_{n}^{*}$ is a compact operator, for all $a\in A$ and $n\in N$, then we say that $\pi$ and $\sigma$ are **approximately unitarily equivalent relative to the compacts.**

**Note that approximate unitary equivalence relative to the compacts is a much stronger notion as it implies that after passing to the Calkin algebra, the representations $\pi $ and $\sigma$ are actually unitarily equivalent.**

My comprehension on the note above is: the $\sigma(a)$ and $\pi(a)$ is unitarily equivalent after passing to Calkin algebra implies 
$$(u^{*}+K(H))(\sigma(a)+K(H))(u+K(H))=\pi(a)+K(H)$$

here, $K(H)$ denotes all the compacts on $H$ and $u+K(H)$ is a unitary in Calkin algebra. So, there exist a compact $K$ such that $u^{*}\sigma(a)u-\pi(a)=K$, this $K$ may unequal to zero. Hence, approximate unitary equivalence relative to the compacts is much stronger notion. Is there anything wrong in my viewpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the comment is saying is that when you assume that $\sigma $ and $\pi$ are approximately unitarily equivalent relative to the compacts, you have $\|\sigma(a)-U_n\pi(a)U_n^*\|\to0$, but also that $\sigma(a)-U_n\pi(a)U_n^*\in K(H)$. So, in the Calkin algebra, $\sigma(a)=U_n\pi(a)U_n^*$ for all $a$ and all $n$ (note that the image of a unitary through the quotient map is again a unitary).

But it is not obvious that approximate unitary equivalence relative to the compacts is "much stronger": when $A$ is separable, the two notions are equivalent. See Theorem II.5.8 in Davidson's book.

Comment: Yeah, maybe my comprehension above is correct. Thanks~